# Express application won't load. It constantly attempts to load in the browser, and doesn't show any errors in the console or browser

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

This is an Express backend with a React front end. React runs perfectly fine on port 3000, and express was running fine on port 3002 until recently. I don't get any error messages and cannot figure out what is going on. Here is my App.js file for the backend:

```js
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cors = require('cors');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var testRouter = require('./routes/test');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(cors());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}))
app.use(bodyParser.json)


app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use("/test", testRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

`

Comment: What db are you using?

Comment: if you put some `console.log`s in there do you see them?

Comment: It also doesn't seem like your app is `listen` ing for any requests or responses. Are you doing that in a separate file?

Comment: I can see any logs to the console. But when I try to go to the browser and go to one of the routes, it doesn't ever load just seems like its stuck in a loop. I had a DB connection to mongoDB but removed it due to this issue. This happened ever since I tried connecting to the DB and querying it. But all those files have been removed and I cannot track down the issue.

Comment: @JustinWade where is your `listen` statement happening? In a separate file?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean when you say React runs fine on port 3000? Are you running a separate server other than express on another port?